# How to get the python-markdown command?

Tags: mac, python, markdown

I'm trying to use python-markdown. I've already followed these steps of installation: http://www.freewisdom.org/projects/python-markdown/Installation, but the command still is unavailable.

I'm running Mac OS X 10.7.

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: @Tshepang `-bash: python-markdown: command not found`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at [this page](http://www.freewisdom.org/projects/python-markdown/Command_Line), which indicated how to run it from the command line (`markdown.py --help`). What you tried to do was running a non-existent command, which happens to be the name of the package. The package name and the binary it provides are not always the same.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the document: https://pythonhosted.org/Markdown/
Some basic examples like:

```
input_file = codecs.open("some_file.txt", mode="r", encoding="utf-8")
text = input_file.read()
html = markdown.markdown(text)
```

or

```
import markdown
html = markdown.markdown(your_text_string)
```